# Why accusative case for который?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

My textbook has the sentence, «Мы живём в гостинице, которую построили финны.»  Given that который is in feminine here, I assume they're it refers to гостиница.  What is the reasoning for который being in the accusative case in this sentence?  I don't understand what verb has гостиница, and thus который, as an object in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a translation will help:

> We live in a hotel, which the Finns have built.

If you were to turn the subordinate clause into a stand-alone sentence, you would get:

> Финны построили гостиницу. (The Finns have built the hotel.)

In this sentence `гостиница` is the object of `построили`, and it must be in the accusative case. Hence `которую` is also in accusative.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Basically, "который" takes gender/number from the noun it refers to, and then you put it the grammatical case required by its role in the subordinate clause. Here, in subordinate clause it is a direct object (what Finns built), hence Accusative. Were it  "A hotel I have read about", you'd use "Гостиница, о которой я читал".